# Função PHP na URL de file_get_contents

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
    $ws1 = file_get_contents('http://10.0.0.0:1111/bids/all/'.$obj->auction_id);
```

Como faço para incluir mais uma barra (**/**) depois de `$obj->id` e colocar mais um código PHP ficando assim:

http://10.0.0.0:1111/bids/all/PHP1/PHP2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seguindo a mesma lógica:

```
$ws1 = file_get_contents('http://10.0.0.0:1111/bids/all/'.$obj->auction_id.'/'.$php2);
//                                                                 Barra ---^
//                                                            Outra variável ---^
```

Em PHP você usa o `.` para concatenar (juntar) duas *strings*.

Troque a variável `$php2` pelo que quiser depois da barra (por exemplo, `$obj->outro_campo`).

Como comentado pelo colega @ValdeirPsr, tem esta outra forma de interpolar:

```
file_get_contents("http://10.0.0.0:1111/bids/all/{$obj->auction_id}/$php2");
```

Sempre que uma *string* é delimitada por aspas duplas, o PHP interpreta os nomes começados por `$` como variáveis. No caso de objetos e algumas expressões, para desambiguar, é preciso usar os delimitadores `{ }` em volta do conjunto.

Comment: Ou então `file_get_contents("http://10.0.0.0:1111/bids/all/{$obj->auction_id}/{$php2}");`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr acrescentei para ficar mais completinha